# Handling exceptions in spawned processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wish to write a process which executes commands from another process. This involves receiving the command, processing it and replying to the calling process with the result. The calling process shall wait for the reply,  before requesting the execution of the next command. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class CommandProcessor(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.command = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.result = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c = self.command.get()
            if not c: break 
            self.result.put(str(c)) 

    def execute(self, n):
        self.command.put(n)
        return self.result.get()

    def stop(self):
        self.command.put(None)
        self.join()

try:
    p = CommandProcessor()
    p.start()
    r = p.execute(1)
    print("Result: "+r)
    r = p.execute(2)
    print("Result: "+r)
    r = p.execute(3)
    print("Result: "+r)
finally:
    p.stop()
```

There is at least one problem with my design. For example, if there is an exception in `CommandProcessor`, the master process will wait indefinitely on the line `return self.result.get()`. I could add a timeout to the `get()` method, but some of the commands I run take a relatively long time to execute. So the timeout will have to be long enough to guarantee their execution. How can I handle this so that both process terminate if there is an exception with a useful stack trace dumped to standard output.

Comment: So wrap it in a ``try/except`` and do *something sensible*.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `try/except`:

**Example:** (*except*)

```
def execute(self, n):
    try:
        self.command.put(n)
        return self.result.get()
    except Exception as e:
        return e  #  TODO: Do something sensible here
```

Comment: This doesn't help since this method is called from the Main process and I'm referring to an exception in the CommandProcessor process.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `run()` method that executes in the spawned process, so that's where you need to do your exception handling. Here's an example, with the stack trace returned as result. Also, note the corrected way of detecting the `None` command (i.e. the "stop" signal).

```
import traceback

class CommandProcessor():
    ...

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c = self.command.get()
            if c is None:
                break
            try:
                1/(c-2)  # Throws exception if c is 2.
            except:
                c = traceback.format_exc()
            self.result.put(str(c))
```

What you get is 1 and 3 works fine, while 2 errs:

```
Result: 1
Result: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 17, in run
    1/(c-2)  # Throws exception if c is 2.
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Result: 3
```